# Override/Shadow a javascript source with another source

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file as below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>abc</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    abcd
    <p>
    efgh
    <a href = "#" id = "link"> Click me </a>
  </body>
<script src = "src1"></script>
<script src = "src2"></script>
</html>
```

The problem: Javascript from src1 is essential for desired functioning for `<p>` tags whereas Javascript from src2 is essential for desired functioning for `<a>` tag. However `<a>` tag works in desired way only if src2 is present and src1 is absent. Fortunately src2 does not affect `<p>`. So, I was wondering if its possible to shadow src1 for `<a>`?

Comment: clean up your code and make a `src3`, so that it caters to both `<a>` and `<p>`

Comment: I can not imagine a such scenario but src2 can always overwrite src1 namespace.. such as if you don't want jQuery you can always make $ = null; and it won't disturb anybody anymore.

Comment: Why do you have script tags after your body? More basically, you should try to figure out why `src1` makes your `<a>` tag logic stop working. Can you show it please?